# Import CSV or .txt File into Outlook contacts programmatically (maybe with C#?)

Tags: c#, csv, import, outlook

How can I do this? I get the data for example ("Max Müller") from Atmega16 over USB to my PC. 
Then I just want to import the contacts to Outlook with ,,a click´´ without doing anything more.
I want it to be automatically. Connecting my Atmega16 with the PC and then automatically importing it to my Outlook contacts. First of all is that even possible? How can I do that? I already searched in Google but couldn´t find anything I´m thankful for every help I get

Zezima

Comment: Loon into this: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268866.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268866.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Sagar Pilkhwal! This might work for me. Which library do I have to add to use the functions given?

Comment: here is a tutorial link [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194126/Creating-an-Outlook-Add-In](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194126/Creating-an-Outlook-Add-In)

Comment: I don't get it what this link has to do with the first one?

Comment: Do I Have to make an Outlook Add in and put the Code from your first link and then do the setup thing? or what did u mean with the tutorial?

Comment: you have to make a outlook-addin.

Comment: Ok thanks Im gonna try this when Im at home since I cant try this on this PC right now. Can u still read this if I still have questions? Im working on a big project right now and I need to get this working (this is just a small step) I´m so thankful for your help (sry for my English not my native language)

Comment: i have worked on outlook addins, dont know if it can b done from an exe but sure i will look into this question and help you out

Comment: Oh right this will be an .exe so it just add it once and then its done? can I use the librarys that I need for the USB connection to get the data from my µC (Atmega16) because it works on a windows form application. because after I connect it with my pc it should add the contacts to outlook. The setup file has to be renewed with the data I get from the µC. U know what I mean?

Comment: So if I make a outlook addin and copy the code in. newContact.FirstName = "Jo";
the string "Jo" needs to get replaced with the string I get from the µC over USB but if I make a outlook addin I have to make a exe file too but then I think its not editable. But it should be editable and overwrite the Jo with the new data I get in. I hope I could explain it right.

Comment: your addin will load the csv from a dir location where µC will copy the csv

Comment: So I Have to Programm the µC to output a csv file? or did I misunderstood you

Comment: Do you have Skype or something so we can chat better?

Comment: No clue if u can read this but i still have some questions and hope that u can help me out a bit

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to parse the CSV/TXT file programmatically. Unlike vCard format, there is no standard format for the CSV files with contact data.